# How to add touch effect to TRectangle in Delphi Firemonkey / Android app?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I want to add touch effect animation (expanding circe) to a `TRectangle`. Same kind of effect that is present on `TButtons` by default - when you put a finger on them they start to draw expanding circle.

I'm looking for the simplest way of doing so, preferrably in the FMX (e.g. take some component from component palette, add it to `Rect1` and configure), not in code.

Why not use custom `TButton`? Well, I'm looking to use only this touch effect and don't need any of the additional button properties / methods.

Comment: you must play with animation connected to trectangle/tcircle placed on the top of your control. It's the way the kiskis app do (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEsEhGfrW-g) using https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe

Comment: @Kromster  - Were you able to do that?

Comment: @Olaf no. Didn't tried more cos we decided it's okay for our app without it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TButtonStyleObject`. Put it on your `TRectangle` with `Align = Contents` and thats all.

Please don't forget to check if your `TButtonStyleObject` has the right Coordinates for the `TTouchAnimationAdapter` Property, otherwise you have to set it manually.

This is a `TButtonStyleObject` example here from Puerto Ricostyle:

```
object TButtonStyleObject
  StyleName = 'Background'
  Align = Contents
  Opacity = 0.100000001490116100
  SourceLookup = 'Puerto Ricostyle.png'
  Size.Width = 184.000000000000000000
  Size.Height = 91.000000000000000000
  Size.PlatformDefault = False
  HotLink = <
    item
      CapInsets.Left = 8.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Top = 8.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Right = 8.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Bottom = 8.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Left = 98.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Top = 195.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Right = 159.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Bottom = 247.000000000000000000
    end
    item
      CapInsets.Left = 12.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Top = 12.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Right = 12.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Bottom = 12.000000000000000000
      Scale = 1.500000000000000000
      SourceRect.Left = 147.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Top = 299.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Right = 241.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Bottom = 376.000000000000000000
    end
    item
      CapInsets.Left = 16.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Top = 16.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Right = 16.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Bottom = 16.000000000000000000
      Scale = 2.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Left = 194.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Top = 398.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Right = 319.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Bottom = 501.000000000000000000
    end
    item
      CapInsets.Left = 24.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Top = 24.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Right = 24.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Bottom = 24.000000000000000000
      Scale = 3.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Left = 294.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Top = 601.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Right = 473.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Bottom = 755.000000000000000000
    end>
  FocusedLink = <
    item
      CapInsets.Left = 8.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Top = 8.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Right = 8.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Bottom = 8.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Left = 97.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Top = 195.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Right = 160.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Bottom = 248.000000000000000000
    end
    item
      CapInsets.Left = 12.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Top = 12.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Right = 12.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Bottom = 12.000000000000000000
      Scale = 1.500000000000000000
      SourceRect.Left = 148.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Top = 299.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Right = 241.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Bottom = 374.000000000000000000
    end
    item
      CapInsets.Left = 16.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Top = 16.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Right = 16.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Bottom = 16.000000000000000000
      Scale = 2.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Left = 192.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Top = 400.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Right = 318.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Bottom = 504.000000000000000000
    end
    item
      CapInsets.Left = 24.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Top = 24.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Right = 24.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Bottom = 24.000000000000000000
      Scale = 3.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Left = 291.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Top = 597.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Right = 483.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Bottom = 749.000000000000000000
    end>
  NormalLink = <
    item
      CapInsets.Left = 8.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Top = 8.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Right = 8.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Bottom = 8.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Left = 99.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Top = 197.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Right = 160.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Bottom = 251.000000000000000000
    end
    item
      CapInsets.Left = 12.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Top = 12.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Right = 12.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Bottom = 12.000000000000000000
      Scale = 1.500000000000000000
      SourceRect.Left = 148.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Top = 299.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Right = 241.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Bottom = 376.000000000000000000
    end
    item
      CapInsets.Left = 16.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Top = 16.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Right = 16.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Bottom = 16.000000000000000000
      Scale = 2.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Left = 194.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Top = 400.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Right = 318.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Bottom = 502.000000000000000000
    end
    item
      CapInsets.Left = 24.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Top = 24.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Right = 24.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Bottom = 24.000000000000000000
      Scale = 3.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Left = 291.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Top = 597.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Right = 478.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Bottom = 749.000000000000000000
    end>
  PressedLink = <
    item
      CapInsets.Left = 8.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Top = 8.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Right = 8.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Bottom = 8.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Left = 100.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Top = 196.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Right = 159.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Bottom = 247.000000000000000000
    end
    item
      CapInsets.Left = 12.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Top = 12.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Right = 12.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Bottom = 12.000000000000000000
      Scale = 1.500000000000000000
      SourceRect.Left = 149.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Top = 299.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Right = 240.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Bottom = 375.000000000000000000
    end
    item
      CapInsets.Left = 16.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Top = 16.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Right = 16.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Bottom = 16.000000000000000000
      Scale = 2.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Left = 194.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Top = 399.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Right = 317.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Bottom = 501.000000000000000000
    end
    item
      CapInsets.Left = 24.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Top = 24.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Right = 24.000000000000000000
      CapInsets.Bottom = 24.000000000000000000
      Scale = 3.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Left = 291.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Top = 600.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Right = 474.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Bottom = 749.000000000000000000
    end>
  TouchAnimation.Link = <
    item
      SourceRect.Left = 238.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Top = 195.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Right = 298.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Bottom = 255.000000000000000000
    end
    item
      Scale = 1.500000000000000000
      SourceRect.Left = 358.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Top = 292.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Right = 448.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Bottom = 382.000000000000000000
    end
    item
      Scale = 2.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Left = 478.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Top = 389.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Right = 598.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Bottom = 509.000000000000000000
    end
    item
      Scale = 3.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Left = 716.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Top = 585.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Right = 897.000000000000000000
      SourceRect.Bottom = 765.000000000000000000
    end>
end
```